# Идея для реализации разметки такого сайта

Tags: html, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка, вёрстка, мобильная-разработка

Скажите пожалуйста как лучше сделать разметку сайта как на картинке? Пробовал на Bootstrap, вроде что то получалось но когда дело дошло до звёздочек, то всё куда то стало само по себе переносится и летать, картинки (ориг. размер 200x200) тяжело подгонялись под размеры мобильных экранов и т.д., я вообще молчу про то что рядов может быть любое количество от 1-4 и длина ряда тоже разная. Так вот каким лучше пользоваться фреймворком в такой ситуации?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Немного не ясно, чем не подошел Bootstrap. Изображение можно сделать адаптированным, что изменялось при растягивании страницы. Насчет блоков, то на 3 не сложно разбить, а потом в мобильной версии они один под второй смещаются. Насчет звездочек, не знаю зачем такая сложная конструкция, но я лично даже не знаю, как без табличной верстки тут обойтись.

Comment: @VyacheslavMartynenko ну звёздочки это у меня просто пример изображения. А как сделать изображения адаптированными? Кстати позиции изображений должны быть строго сохранены, то есть чтобы не переносились друг под друга во время сужения браузера и то что вы говорите "даже не знаю, как без табличной верстки тут обойтись", мне не надо замены табличной верстки, мне просто разобраться бы с ней

Comment: Насчет изображений - http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp. Насчет переносов, то все задается в разметке, что за чем следует, и будет ли у блоков возможность нырять друг под друга, при необходимости. Насчет звездочек и табличной верстки, я имел ввиду, что слишком сложный момент, если требуется, что бы в одном месте была пустота, а в другом контент, тот тут кроме того, как задать все стандартной html таблицей, варианта не вижу. Если контент есть везде, то опять же все просто разбивается через bootstrap.

Comment: @VyacheslavMartynenko а у вы могли бы посоветовать какую нибудь инфу по табличной растоновке пожалуйста при помощи стандартных средств?

Comment: Точнее как адаптировать таблицу под экран, а картинки адаптировать под каждую ячейку таблицы?

Comment: По поводу адаптированных изображений, я вам сбросил выше ссылку.  По поводу таблицы - задавать относительные параметры. В целом верстку можно построить и на разделении страницы на большее количество строк-подстрок бутстрапа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используя bootstrap, я поступаю следующим образом:
Для примера, на странице нужно установить картинку 200x200

1. Я устанавливаю картинке width:100% и max-width:200px
2. Прописываю отдельные стили под различные размеры экрана, например выравниваю по центру

Что касается ваших картинок(звездочек). Каждое изображение поместите в отдельный блок div(рекомендую использовать col-md-.., col-sm-.., col-xs-..) и все, вы достигните результата.